# Dataframe apply(map) function TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

Can someone please point out the error of my ways with this piece of code:

```
groupIds = allData.drop_duplicates('GroupID').set_index('Ticket')['GroupID']

allData.loc[(allData['SexGroup']!='Man') & (allData['GroupID']=='Alone'), 'GroupID'].apply(lambda x: x['Ticket'].map(groupIds).fillna('Alone'))
```

Error is:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
string indices must be integers
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Data

```
             Survived  Pclass                                               Name     Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch            Ticket     Fare Cabin Embarked Title SexGroup    Surname     TicketShort  FamilySize  Alone  IsWomanOrChild  SurnameFreq GroupID
PassengerId
1                 0.0       3                            Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  22.0      1      0         A/5 21171   7.2500   NaN        S    Mr      Man     Braund         A/5 211           2  False           False            0   Alone
2                 1.0       1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...  female  38.0      1      0          PC 17599  71.2833   C85        C   Mrs    Woman    Cumings          PC 175           2  False            True            1   Alone
3                 1.0       3                             Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26.0      0      0  STON/O2. 3101282   7.9250   NaN        S  Miss    Woman  Heikkinen  STON/O2. 31012           1   True            True            1   Alone
4                 1.0       1       Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)  female  35.0      1      0            113803  53.1000  C123        S   Mrs    Woman   Futrelle            1138           2  False            True            1   Alone
5                 0.0       3                           Allen, Mr. William Henry    male  35.0      0      0            373450   8.0500   NaN        S    Mr      Man      Allen            3734           1   True           False            1   Alone
```

EDIT 2:

The code is supposed to go through all the GroupIDs where the sex is female and the current GroupID is 'Alone'. Then, if those conditions are met, for that row, check if the 'Ticket' value occurs elsewhere in the 'Ticket' column. If yes, return the GroupID for that occurrence. If not, leave it 'Alone'

Comment: can you please post some data too? where we can replicate and resolve this?

Comment: Paste `allData.head()` will help.

Comment: Apologies, will do

Comment: you are using `.apply` on a Series.

Comment: In your `lambda` function, `x` is a string.

Comment: I'd begin by using `.loc[ (.....), :]` instead of `.loc[(.....), 'GroupBy']`

Comment: But then it will change all the columns not only the 'GroupID' column no?

Comment: @RafaelC you are correct. 'x' is the value for the GroupID cell... how to have 'x' be the row of the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone trying to do something similar, this worked for me:

```
allData.loc[(allData['SexGroup']!='Man') & (allData['GroupID']=='Alone'), 'GroupID'] = allData['Ticket'].map(groupIds).fillna('Alone')
```